# Shooting method on non-linear third ordered differential equation with boundary conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know that how to apply the shooting method on first and second ordered non linear ordinary differential equations. I want to apply this method on third ordered case. I need the standard references for this problem. For example $f^{'''}+ff^{''}-f^{'2}=0$ with boundary condition $f(0)=0,\, f^{'}(0)=1,\,f^{'}(\infty)=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you expect an asymptotically constant behavior, the third derivative becomes faster small than the other two. For a more precise treatment of this idea see: [How to solve an ODE with $y^{-1}$ term](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610416/how-to-solve)

So approximately for large $x$ one has $f(x)f''(x)-f'(x)^2=0$ and thus $f(x)=ae^{-bx}$ with $b>0$. Enhance that to $f(x)=ae^{-bx}+c$ to get non-zero asymptotics and insert into the ODE to get
$$-b^3ae^{bx}+(ae^{bx}+c)ab^2e^{bx}-a^2b^2e^{2bx}=0\implies c=b.$$

In the shooting method you select some large $X$ as start of the asymptotic segment and solve on $[0,X]$ the boundary value problem with additional constant parameters $a,b$ and the right side boundary condition $f(X)=ae^{-bX}+b$, $f'(X)=-abe^{-bX}$, $f''(X)=ab^2e^{-bX}$ or $f''(X)=-bf'(X)$.

Implementing this for several values of $X$ gives in this case excellent convergence for even small values of $X$, as apparently $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ is already the exact solution.

[image]